# Is there any way to get current executing generic method with generic arguments?

Tags: c#, reflection

So, let's say I have class

```cs
public class Sample<T>
{
    // (1)
    public static void StaticMethod1() {
        
    }

    // (2)
    public static T2 StaticMethod2<T2>() where T2 : new() {
        return new T2();
    }

    // (3)
    public void InstanceMethod1() {
        
    }
    
    // (4)
    public T2 InstanceMethod2<T2>() where T2: new () {
        return new T2();
    }
}
```

And I want to get methods with concrete generic arguments:

1. T
2. T, T2
3. T
4. T, T2

So, for now, I know how to get what I need only for third method
`GetType().GetMethod("InstanceMethod1)` since `GetType` returns type with generic arguments (but cannot be called in static context), but how to do it in other cases? Is there any way at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to construct `Sample<>` with concrete generic parameter. You can use [`MakeGenericType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=net-5.0) for that:

```cs
var concreteType = typeof(Sample<>).MakeGenericType(new []{typeof(SomeConcreteType)})
```

And then you can use `GetMethod` and [`MakeGenericMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=net-5.0):

```cs
var concreteMethod = concreteType.GetMethod("InstanceMethod2").MakeGenericMethod(new []{ typeof(SomeType2) });
```

**UPD**

To to do what you've described in the comment you need to use `typeof(T)` and `typeof(T2)` in corresponding places:

```cs
public class Gen<T>
{
    public void Test<T1>() => Console.WriteLine($"<{typeof(T)}> - <{typeof(T1)}>");
}

new Gen<int>().Test<string>(); // prints <System.Int32> - <System.String>
```

Comment: No, it's not what I want. I want to call Sample<int>.StaticMethod<int>() and method needs to find out what arguments it was called with.

Comment: @batangaming then you need to just use `typeof(T)` and `typeof(T2)`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about it right now. Yeah, you're right, that's exactly what I should do, don't know why I didn't think about it early. Thanks a lot

Comment: @batangaming was glad to help